# HTML page with Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to get my radio buttons to direct me to the webpage after you make your selection and hit submit. This is the code I have thus far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
  <h1>Radio Buttons</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form method="post" action="demoform.asp">
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
      <legend>Choose a Website:</legend>
        <label for="ESPN.com">ESPN.com</label>
        <input type="radio" name="website" id="ESPN.com" value="http://espn.go.com">
        <label for="Facebook.com">Facebook.com</label>
        <input type="radio" name="website" id="Facebook.com" value="https://www.facebook.com">
        <label for="Apple.com">Apple.com</label>
        <input type="radio" name="website" id="Apple.com" value="http://www.apple.com"> 
      </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot to post your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
function whichsite(form){
    var sites = form.elements.site, i = sites.length;
    while (--i > -1){
        if(sites[i].checked){
            return sites[i].value;
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" onsubmit="window.open(whichsite(this), '_blank'); return false;">
<b>Where do you need to go?:</b>
<p>
<label><input type="radio" name="site" value="http://yahoo.com/">Yahoo</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="site" value="http://google.com/">Google</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="site" value="http://amazon.com/">Amazon</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="site" value="http://cnn.com/" checked>CNN</label>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the event onclick = "document.location.href='somepage.htm'" inside your input radio tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery like this:

```
$('input:radio[name="website"]').change(
    function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == '1') {
            window.location = "http://espn.go.com";
        }
        else if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == '2'){
            window.location = "https://www.facebook.com";
        }
        else if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == '3'){
            window.location = "http://www.apple.com";
        }
    });
```

**HTML Radio Buttons**

```
<input type="radio" name="website" id="ESPN.com" value="1">
<label for="Facebook.com">Facebook.com</label>
<input type="radio" name="website" id="Facebook.com" value="2">
<label for="Apple.com">Apple.com</label>
<input type="radio" name="website" id="Apple.com" value="3">
```

Comment: I will give this a try

Comment: @JoeySchwind I thought the requirement was for the navigation to happen after the form was submitted, not on change of the radio buttons?